# Can I reuse LDPE bottles after trace element analysis?

Tags: stoichiometry, cleaning

I run some algae samples through mass spec a few times over the month to test the P content of algal samples. My (simplified) procedure was as follows:

1. Put a small portion of algae in a teflon vessel
2. Add nitric acid and hydrogen peroxide in the teflon vessel
3. Put that teflon vessel in a microwave digestion system and run it for an hour
4. Add deionized water to the solution
5. Put the sample on a hotplate and let it reduce over night.
6. Add more nitric acid to the solution
7. Transfer the solution to a 125 ml LDPE bottle
8. Add deionized water to the solution until it reaches 100 grams

I have decided to run this procedure a few more times so I bought 250 ml LDPE bottles for my experiments and to replace some bottles that I used from another lab. I am not experienced in chemistry at all and a tech has been helping me with these experiments, which I am grateful for. Today I asked the tech how I can clean the bottles to return them to the lab and he told me that those bottles were just thrown away after being used for trace elemental analysis.

I am honestly shocked because they cost like $300 for 30 of these bottles. I need to run over 200 samples and I can't afford to keep replacing these bottles. I have no doubt in the tech's experience and they have been teaching me, but I find it odd that these bottles can't be used again for trace element analysis especially since the teflon and PFA beakers can be reused multiple times and I never heated or reheated these bottles. I simply do not have enough knowledge to understand why I can't soak these bottles in HNO3 for 7 days and call it good? Have any of you tried to clean these bottles after trace elemental analysis?

Thanks!

Comment: He's got a point.

Comment: Well, if you were sure they won't affect the measurements... but I guess that would call for special cleaning protocol and testing for elements and adjusting the protocol... which would likely cost much more.

Comment: I clean the teflon and the PFA beakers using nitric acid so It seems odd that there is not a protocol for cleaning LDPE after trace element analysis. I mean, I am a beginner so there has to one somewhere right? I don't test if my cleaning of the PFA and the teflon has gone well because I assume there is a tried and true protocol that has already been done many times.

Comment: LDPE is quite different than PFA, perhaps there would be an issue with leftover traces of catalyst used in polymerisation? Wait for some specialist here or ask another IRL.

Comment: Apparently, the the lab buys economy LDPE bottles so they cost $2 which is way more cost-efficient than what I bought. I returned the bottles and will be using the economy bottles for the next run.